# AT#MONI on Huawei 3G modem (model E3131) not working

Tags: geolocation, at-command, 3g

I try to locate my position using 3G modem connected to my PC and the triangulation method.
So, I need to identify the cell towers id in my neighborhood and to do that I use AT commands and specifically AT#MONI=7.

I know how to determine the cell tower id that my 3G modem is actually connected (I tape "AT+CREG=2" and then "AT+CREG?") but not how to determine a set of cell towers to be able to use triangulation method.

I use PUTTY to establish connection with my 3G modem.

It's very important for me to do this job, so thanks in advance for all those will try to help me.

Comment: I don't get any response until now. Is the question doesn't clear enough

Comment: Could you please, give me a Huawei 3G modem dongle (mobile broadband) model, on which you have tested "AT#MONI=7" command and work fine.

Comment: :-) where are you good developers

Comment: I contact Huawei"s technical support but it doesn't reply me. I just want a 3G modem dongle model on which I could run "AT^MONI" command. It's very important for me to do this job. So, please, anyone could help me I will be very grateful for him. Thanks for all.

Comment: I am disappointed to not be able to get response after all this time. I am in critical situation. I just want to know if anybody had tried this AT command on 3g modem key and give me it's model.

Comment: ... to be continued :-)

Comment: I have the same issue, and I worry AT#MONI (aka AT+MONI) is not supported by this model. What I get from modem: "COMMAND NOT SUPPORT"

Comment: Thanks zuko, please if you fond a model that support this command notify me

Comment: I tried 2 different ones, but finally I deiced to build a combo with E3131 and cheap GPS module like MTK3339 (faster and cheaper)